# Migrate FTP users from one server to another

Tags: server, ftp, migration, users

I have a situation where I have ~10 FTP users, and I need to migrate them from one server (server A) to another (server B).

The userdata (so their files) are in `/home/<username>`, so moving that is as simple as an `rsync` job.

I also need to keep their existing usernames/passwords etc - if it's at all possible, the users shouldn't notice that they had the server switched on them.

Is there a "easy" way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking all you need to do is migrate the relevant lines in `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow` and the group variants (`/etc/group` and `/etc/gshadow`) along with home files.

You might be able to just clone these files over but I think it's probably better to strip out the system accounts which might (poor design, but they might) store their passwords around the system which might be different on your new installation.

The best guide I've seen to do this selectively is [this one](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-move-migrate-user-accounts-old-to-new-server/). Just be careful that in the end you're using `>>` to append the old user accounts on to the new server's files and not `>` which would replace them.

Comment: I'm moving from an ancient Ubuntu which has root access by default (*shudder*) to 10.04, so I'm *NOT* keeping the entire system accounts :P

Comment: Just be aware that the password hashing/encryption scheme can change between versions (especially if you are going from 32-bit to 64-bit) and so copying over the passwords (/etc/shadow) may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how users authenticated. It could be against /etc/passwd, external database, internal database or even LDAP.

If it's /etc/passwd — then you need just to recreate users and copy hashes from /etc/shadow on server A to server B.

External/internal DB — just move data.

LDAP — I don't really think that you are using this one ;)

Comment: Definitely *not* ldap. ;)